# Angular-Material ngMessage not working when using ng-repeat with ng-message-exp directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

I'm trying to make work form validation using angular-material. This form is using ng-messages for error messaging from a json in the controller. My view looks like:

```
    <md-input-container flex>
      <label>email2</label>
      <input name="email2" ng-model="email2" required ng-minlength="5" type="text" value="{{ email2 }}" />
      <ng-messages for="form3.email2.$error">
        <div ng-repeat="m in errors">
          <div ng-message-exp="m.expression">{{m.description}}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-messages>
    </md-input-container>
```

The code works without the ng-repeat directive but cannot see why with ng-repeat breaks.

A codepen example of this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeGBRm

Answer (score 3):

It will work as soon as you add required dependency on ngMessages module:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```

Also, `ng-messages` element doesn't work well as a child of `md-input-container` (overlays input), so you might want to make `ng-messages {display: block;}`.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyVVPW